# Android dynamically create String Array from XML string resources, without XML string array

Tags: android, android-xml

Ok, so this question is a bit weird, and kinda rubs me the wrong to even ask, but since I probably don't have a choice I want to see what you guys think. I'm still a novice at Java and Android.

The case is as follows: We are trying to automate the building of our strings.xml for localisation. A parser has been made to convert a csv-file to xml. For regular strings it's not a real problem, that works fine. But the parser that was built, doesn't take string arrays into account and there is little chance that someone will modify it.

Is there an "easy" way to work with the strings and create an string array programmatically based on parts the name attributes?

If not, then I would have to hard code the arrays and that leaves the creator (client) of the language files unable to add items to something that should be a dynamic list.

I know modifying the strings.xml manually might be an option, but because our management wants to automate stuff like that, it's not much of a choice I have.

Probably I will hard code the stuff and say they can't dynamically fill the lists, but still (also for my personal education) I wanna know what you guys think.

Thanks for your opinions or solutions. :)

Cheers!

Comment: the strings.xml will be created when app is running or before building the project ? please make this clear.

Comment: Hi, sorry, the strings.xml is created before building the project, but it has to be parsed by another application.

So, in theory I could modify the xml manually, but that is not the way they want it to work. Because we would have to charge the client each time a new iteration of the product is released, while they already made the strings file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So you will get **strings.xml** as below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string name="string1">1st string</string>
    <string name="string2">2nd string</string>
                 ........
    <string name="stringN">Nth string</string>
</resources>
```

I suggest a simple modification to strings.xml, which is add a string with name count at top of all strings with value equal to total number of strings and add another string with name prefix below the count, then it looks like as below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string name="count">4</string>
    <string name="prefix">string</string>
    <string name="string1">1st string</string>
    <string name="string2">2nd string</string>
    <string name="string3">3rd string</string>
    <string name="string4">4th string</string>
</resources>
```

So now, in your java file you can access them like below

```
int count = Integer.parseInt(getString(R.string.count));
        String prefix = getString(R.string.prefix);
        String[] strings = new String[count];
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            strings[i] = getString(getResources().getIdentifier(prefix+(i+1), "string", getPackageName()));
        }
```

I hope it may help you.

Comment: This one makes sense, it's almost the same as the solution Jens submitted, but yours is bit more comprehensive. Thanks! 

Like I thought, we won't include this in our first version of the app, but it's an actual solution, which I would like to see in a future version update. :)

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

You can use (& really really *really* should anyways) references in string arrays. Assuming this is your generated `res/values/strings.xml` in Swedish:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string name="string1">Hej, detta är på svenska</string>
    <string name="string2">Denna strängen också</string>
</resources>
```

You can put your `string-array` in, for instance, `res/values/arrays.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string-array name="somearrayname">
        <item>@string/string1</item>
        <item>@string/string1</item>
    </string-array>
</resources>
```

Comment: Hi Jens, 
Thanks, this is the way I would have done it myself and imho is the only way it should be done, and that was what I was also trying to refer to, and I would like it very much if the parser would give me string arrays, but it doesn't, so I'm basically stuck, looking for another solution than make the array manually.

Comment: Well, the idea is that you put your arrays in a *different* XML document altogether - while using references into strings.xml - which you automatically generate. This should work for you, unless you for some reason need to make the string-arrays variable for each translation?